# useSelector is unable to fetch latest value of state after re-render and return null

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a user page, in which i am getting user info from state itself using useState hook of redux.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import profileImage from "../../resources/images/defaultProfile.png";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { userActions } from "../../state/actions";

const User = () => {
  const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState(false);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      [e.target.name]: [e.target.value],
    });
  };
  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (!isEditable) {
      setIsEditable(!isEditable);
    } else {
      //TODO update user data here
    }
  };
  const [user, setUser] = useState(useSelector((state) => state.user.user));

  return (
    user !== null && (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-9 border border-primary">user preference</div>
          <div className="col-md-3 border border-primary">
            <div className="row-cols-md-3 text-center">
              <img
                src={profileImage}
                alt="Profile image"
                style={{ width: "60%", height: "70%" }}
                className="border rounded-circle"
              />

              <form onSubmit={onSubmit} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <label htmlFor="userName" className="form-label">
                    User Name
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    id="userName"
                    value={user.name}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    disabled={!isEditable ? "disabled" : ""}
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <label htmlFor="userEmail" className="form-label">
                    User Email
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    disabled={!isEditable ? "disabled" : ""}
                    id="userEmail"
                    value={user.email}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <label htmlFor="userPhone" className="form-label">
                    User Phone Number
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    disabled={!isEditable ? "disabled" : ""}
                    name="phoneno"
                    id="userPhone"
                    value={user.phoneno}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                </div>

                <button type="submit">{isEditable ? "Update" : "Edit"}</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export default User;
```

The data is loading fine for the first time. As shown initially all my input field are disabled but once i click on edit, it changes state isEditable and enables every field and change the submit button to "update" .It's ***re-render*** the ***page*** once the ***state isEditable*** is changed. I am ***loading navbar*** by default for every page and navBar has ***code which reloads*** the value of user state in case of refresh and once the page re-renders it reloads the user global state ***but somehow useSelector is unable to get latest value and just returns the null value***.

Observation -
once the complete re-renders happen useSelector is unable to fetch latest user data although the state has the latest value.

Can somebody please suggest what approach should i choose to overcome the following scenerio.

Comment: very bad code structure. remove useSelectror from useState.

Comment: Sorry but i am new to it and initially it was outside only but i was testing multiple scenarios so that's when i did this.

Comment: setUser update your state with new value and removed useSelector :)

Comment: @NijatAliyev please correct me if i misinterpreting the code, my useSelector is fetching the value from from global user state and setting it to local state of user and setUser will only be called once there is some change in the input field which is only possible when the fields are editable, so setUser should never be called in my case. Please suggest.

Comment: useState and redux are differ state managment. you are now mixed. remov useSelector from useState and write to top area, useSelector just fetch data from redux state, setUser update your component state,   if you need get last result from useSelector, you must be update redux state with dispatch too.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but its still not working, what i noticed is, when page reloads my global user state becomes empty and so did my component  state but as i said my NavBar is loading default for every page and it sets global user value but component user state still remains empty, i tried putting if else condition in case of component state user empty but its causing double clicking of edit button, after that it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Never do
`useState(useSelector(...));`

It does not do what you expect.

`useState` is initialized once with the argument you put into it - so at first render, it will "capture" the value the selector returns at that point in time. But it will never update the state once the return value from `useSelector` changes. The local state is initialized after all.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this knowledge. I am new to react, can you suggest how can i set local component state after reloading of page, after debugging i tried if else condition to use useState based on component state empty and global state not, but then it has some repercussion and i have to click on edit button twice.

Comment: On a page reload, state is gone - and most users will probably expect that anyways, since that is how the internet works. F5 refreshes stuff and resets things.

Answer (score 0):

Well i was surfing internet for the following issue and i found this.
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-forms-tutorial/
" By default, when clicking the form’s Submit button, the browser performs a full-page POST request to the URL specified in the action attribute of the . But having the form controlled by React, you can prevent browser’s default behavior by attaching an event handler to onSubmit event and calling event.preventDefault(). "

And based on this i bring my button out of the form, since now no complete post request would be called and hence it started working.

Frankly i am still not sure, earlier why it was working fine after second click.